# Expanding inside multiple braces

Tags: expl3, expansion, braces

I find expansion in LaTeX really confusing :(.

Consider the following `expl3` code:

(Note that `\l_tmpa_tl` and `\l_tmpb_tl` are set elsewhere. So I can't just say `\cs_set_nopar:Nn \dcp_baz: { { xyz } { \S 6 } }`. Neither can I say `\cs_set_nopar:Nn \dcp_baz: { { \l_tmpa_tl } { \l_tmpb_tl } }`. I need it expanded. But I don't want it exhaustively expanded. I just want to recover what's in the variables `\l_tmpa_tl` and `\l_tmpb_tl`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_nopar:Nn \dcp_foo:
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { xyz }
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpb_tl { \S 6 }
    \exp_args:NVV \dcp_bar:nn \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpb_tl
    \dcp_baz:
  }
\cs_new_nopar:Nn \dcp_bar:nn
  {
    \cs_set_nopar:Nn \dcp_baz: { {#1} {#2} }
  }
\cs_set_eq:NN \Foo \dcp_foo:
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\Foo
\end{document}
```

This does what I want, in that `\dcp_baz:` ends up being a macro containing `{xyz}{\S 6}`.

However, I have two questions:

1. Can I do this in `expl3` without the helper function `\dcp_bar:nn`?
2. How would I do this in LaTeX2e?

Comment: what is "this"  though here? as your top level `\foo`/`dcp_foo:` doesn't take arguments your two tmp macros aren't really needed, then you wouldn't need the helper to expand them and the answer to (2) would be `\newcommand\Foo{\def\dcpBaz{{xyz}{\S 6}}}  \Foo`  but is that the answer you need?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, sigh always wanting clarity :). xyz and \S 6 are in macros that are set elsewhere.

Comment: that;s what I suspected, would have been clearer to set them outside the macro probably but anyway I posted an answer to 2, I'll see if I can think of the correct idom for 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of versions for 2 then 1

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\FooA{\def\dcpBaz{{xyz}{\S 6}}}
\FooA \show\dcpBaz

\newcommand\FooB{%
  \def\tmpa{xyz}%
  \def\tmpb{\S 6}%
  \edef\dcpBaz{%
     {\unexpanded\expandafter{\tmpa}}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\tmpb}}}}
    \FooB \show\dcpBaz

in a pure expl3 universe \verb|\S| would be etex protected not via `\verb|\protect|`
so

\protected\def\newS{\S}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_nopar:Nn \dcp_foo:
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { xyz }
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpb_tl { \newS 6 }
    \cs_set_nopar:Nx \dcp_baz: { {\l_tmpa_tl} {\l_tmpb_tl} }
    \show\dcp_baz:
  }
\cs_set_eq:NN \FooC \dcp_foo:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\FooC
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes! I think `\FooB` is the kind of thing I'm after. I was using `\edef` without the `\unexpanded\expandafter`. This is what I mean when I say that i find expansion confusing. I don't actually really understand your answer :).

Comment: @DavidPurton expl3 version being added

Comment: @DavidPurton the `\expandafter` expands the `\tmpb` then the `\unexpanded` stops any further expansion, eg of `\S`.

Comment: Isn't using `\newS` kind of cheating? `\S` is what was breaking the code I was using (before asking this question). It's not reasonable to expect a user to redefine `\S` before using it.

Comment: @DavidPurton well that depends, if you leave \S defined as `\protect\Sspace` then you will need a helper function or directly write the \fooB version just using the expl3 renamed versions of \unexpanded and \expandafter . You wouldn't need that if the macros being used were defined by expl3 commands as they are either safe to expand or etex \protected.  so the idiomatic expl3 way is as I show here but it doesn't work for \S as that isn't defined by expl3. It's the price you pay for having expl3 not a clean start latex3 without the 2e compatibility issues.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. So in theory I could do: `\cs_set_nopar:Nn \dcp_baz: { \exp_not:n \exp_after:wN { \l_tmpa_tl } \exp_not:n \exp_after:wN { \l_tmpb_tl } }`. But that's not really nice `expl3`, right?

Comment: @DavidPurton yes more or less the intention of the :neXVnnn argument specifiers are that you don't need the chains of \expandafter that you classically need, and just writing \expandafter as \exp_after:wN isn't really an improvement,  but here (unless I missed something) you need something like that or your helper version as in the question.